# How can I restart git bash?

Tags: git

Various documentation such as

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

and

http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/

Refer to restarting git bash. How do I do this from Linux?

Comment: `git bash` is a tool for Windows that provides a Linux-like command line so that Windows users can use the git command-line tools.

Comment: @larsks Why don't you put that in an answer so this question can be closed?

Comment: Eh, someone's already done that.

Comment: it is not a real answer, it does not explain why whould some app need to restart it and what exactly should be restarted? The git-bash window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is referring to the Git Bash shell which is installed via Cygwin on Windows systems. If you need to do this on Linux, simply close and reopen your terminal window. Often you can replace this step with `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: How would I restart Git Bash shell on windows?

Comment: You should just be able to close it and reopen it. If this doesn't solve your problem, you should ask a new question instead of looking for answers in the comments of other questions.

Comment: Closing and re-opening the window doesn't echo `Initializing new SSH agent…` like it did the first time, so my guess is that this isn't sufficient. How would one stop or restart Git Bash properly so that it also restarts the SSH agent?

Comment: Wait, I just figured out: the function `start_agent` that is created in `~/.bashrc`, you can manually call it in Git Bash again. — Alternatively (and probably better), you can open the Task manager and end `ssh-agent.exe` before re-opening Git Bash.